# Is there any good good resource on how to write a ndis filter with windows develop kit?

Tags: wdk, ndis

Although wdk ships an exampe with it,it doesn't have any detail documents on how it works.

Is there any resource that fully explains how it works?

Answer (score 0):

It does very much contain all that you need.

> **NDIS Filter Drivers**
>
> Filter drivers are supported in NDIS
>   6.0 and later versions. You should use filter drivers instead of filter
>   intermediate drivers. For more
>   information about intermediate
>   drivers, see NDIS 6.0 Intermediate
>   Drivers.
>
> The following sections introduce
>   filter drivers and describe how to
>   write and install filter drivers:
>
> Roadmap for Developing NDIS Filter
>   Drivers
>
> Introduction to NDIS Filter Drivers
>
> Writing NDIS Filter Drivers
>
> NDIS Filter Driver Installation

This quote can be found in the index of the WDK documentation under "NDIS Filter Drivers". And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565501%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is the link to MSDN. Although the WDK docs you install locally and this link are not identical. All you need to know is on these pages - except that you should have preliminary knowledge of drivers and kernel mode development for Windows.